# Count n-grams with token_count field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Is it possible to count number of produced n-grams using `token_count` field?
Let's suppose I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "trigrams_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "trigrams": {
          "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["lowercase", "trigrams_filter"]
          }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "trigrams",
          "fields": {
            "length": { 
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "trigrams"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this mapping I'd expect to get three terms for value "quick": "qui", "uic" and "ick", but the following query doesn't return any hit despite the fact that `message.length` field has `trigrams` analyzer:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "message.length": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `http://localhost:9200/{index_name}/_analyze?text=apple&analyzer=trigrams` which is `_analyze` api to see what tokens it generated on your text. More info on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_testing_analyzers.html And https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html let me know if it solves ur issue or u requires any other info.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Thank you for response! I'm aware of this API but it is not what I'm looking for. This API cannot be used in search queries the same way you can use `token_count`. I'm just wondering why token_count field does not take into account produced n-grams.